# How to install youtube-to-gif in the Linux server?

Tags: linux, node.js, youtube, ffmpeg, installation

Hi I am using Linux cloud server. I have successfully installed `ffmpeg` and `nodeJS` by server support team. But I am unable to install youtube-to-gif

My nodeJS version is - **2.5.1**
ffmpeg version is - **0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.1**

I have tried to  installed `youtube-to-gif` in following command

```
$ sudo npm install youtube-to-gif -g
```

or

```
$ npm install youtube-to-gif -g
```

This two command not working. I saw `youtube-to-gif` installed in the node_modules directory but when i am typing  `$ youtube-to-gif -h` I got this error message

```
-bash: youtube-to-gif: command not found
```

[image]

YouTube to GIF command

```
youtube-to-gif -u https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqxSgp385N0 -b 30 -d 5
```

SERVER

[image]

Local

[image]

Document - https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-to-gif

I am not sure this is perfectly installed or not. But `youtube-to-gif` command not working. Can you please help me.

Comment: is node_modules directory in the $PATH?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk can you check my updated question

Comment: you did not answer my question.

Comment: Which `$PATH` you are asking? Please check node_modules path on that screenshot

Comment: the $PATH; clarification: there is only one. just google, seriously!

Comment: I have not set any `path` in my local machine. But this is working fine.